# Unsupported Media Type error spring boot api JAVA

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot, api, file, amazon-s3

I'm developing a product registration API, in my post I send information about my product by Json and also send an image file directly to my amazon s3. The problem is that when doing this in my postman, I am getting the error

```
    "status": 415,
    "error": "Unsupported Media Type"
```

I suspect it's some problem with my RequestPart or even the postman. In my postman, I send the jsons in raw and send the file in form-data with file name

this is the controller

```
package com.api.business_manager_api.Controllers;

import com.api.business_manager_api.Dtos.ProductDto;
import com.api.business_manager_api.Mappers.ProductMapper;
import com.api.business_manager_api.Models.CategoryModel;
import com.api.business_manager_api.Models.ProductModel;
import com.api.business_manager_api.Services.CategoryService;
import com.api.business_manager_api.Services.ProductService;
import jakarta.validation.Valid;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;
import org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.S3Client;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.model.PutObjectRequest;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;
import java.util.UUID;

@RestController
@CrossOrigin(origins = "*", maxAge = 3600)
@RequestMapping("/product")
public class ProductController {
    final ProductService productService;
    final CategoryService categoryService;
    final ProductMapper productMapper;
    final S3Client s3Client;

    private final String BUCKET_NAME = "awstockproducts" + System.currentTimeMillis();

    public ProductController(ProductService productService, ProductMapper productMapper, CategoryService categoryService, S3Client s3Client) {
        this.productService = productService;
        this.productMapper = productMapper;
        this.categoryService = categoryService;
        this.s3Client = s3Client;
    }
    @PostMapping(consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<Object> saveProduct (@RequestPart("productDto") @Valid ProductDto productDto, @RequestPart("file")MultipartFile file) {
        try {
            if (productService.existsByProduct(productDto.getProduct())) {
                return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.CONFLICT).body("Product already exists!");
            }
            ProductModel productModel = productMapper.toProductModel(productDto);
            CategoryModel categoryModel = categoryService.findById(productDto.getProductCategory().getCategory_id())
                    .orElseThrow(() -> new RuntimeException("Category not found"));
            productModel.setProductCategory(categoryModel);

            String fileName = "/products/images/" + UUID.randomUUID().toString() + "-" + file.getOriginalFilename();

            s3Client.putObject(PutObjectRequest
                            .builder()
                            .bucket(BUCKET_NAME)
                            .key(fileName)
                            .build(),
                        software.amazon.awssdk.core.sync.RequestBody.fromString("Testing java sdk"));
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.CREATED).body(productService.save(productModel));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.CONFLICT).body("Cannot create product. Check if the fields sent in your request are correct.");
        }
    }

    @GetMapping
    public ResponseEntity<List<ProductModel>> getAllProducts() {
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK).body(productService.findAll());
    }

    @GetMapping("/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<Object> getOneProduct(@PathVariable(value = "id")UUID id) {
        Optional<ProductModel> productModelOptional = productService.findById(id);
        if (!productModelOptional.isPresent()) {
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND).body("Product not found");
        }
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK).body(productModelOptional.get());
    }

    @PutMapping("/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<Object> updateProduct(@PathVariable(value = "id") UUID id,
                                                @RequestBody @Valid ProductDto productDto) {
        Optional<ProductModel> productModelOptional = productService.findById(id);
        if (!productModelOptional.isPresent()) {
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND).body("Product not found!");
        }
        ProductModel productModel = productModelOptional.get();
        productModel.setProduct(productDto.getProduct());
        productModel.setDescription(productDto.getDescription());
        productModel.setPrice(productDto.getPrice());
        productModel.setExtraPrice(productDto.getExtraPrice());
        productModel.setStock(productDto.getStock());
        productModel.setProductCategory(productDto.getProductCategory());

        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK).body(productService.save(productModel));
    }

    @DeleteMapping("/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<Object> deleteProduct(@PathVariable(value = "id") UUID id) {
        Optional<ProductModel> productModelOptional = productService.findById(id);
        if (!productModelOptional.isPresent()) {
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND).body("Product not found!");
        }
        productService.delete(productModelOptional.get());
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK).body("Product deleted succesfully!");
    }
}
```

console error

```
.w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException: Content-Type 'application/json' is not supported]
```

Answer (score 0):

You must send all the content of your requests in a multipart form.

```
--HereGoes
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="myJsonString"
Content-Type: application/json

{"foo": "bar"}
--HereGoes
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="photo"
Content-Type: image/jpeg
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64

<...JPEG content in base64...>
--HereGoes--
```